# Whats the name of this izakaya?

Tags: translation, parsing, reading-comprehension

everyone I was in an awsome izakaya in Osaka but wasnt able to figure out the name of it and stuff like it is private owned or of a chain.

Below is a picture of its front (google translate etc. cant translate it).
Its behind Tennoji Station in Osaka.

Thanks alot in Advance!

[image]

Comment: https://www.hotpepper.jp/strJ001036886/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in Japanese by [the link that l'électeur posted in the comment](https://www.hotpepper.jp/strJ001036886/), the name is a bit long:

- 串【くし】カツ天下茶屋【てんがちゃや】 カメちゃん 天王寺店【てんのうじてん】

Names of stores that end in ～店 often indicate that this is a branch of a chain.  In the above Japanese, the 天王寺店【てんのうじてん】 on the end tells us that this is the "Tennōji store".  That matches what you've told us about this place.

[Here's a Google search that also spits out the name in *romaji* (the Latin alphabet)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A1%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93%22+%E5%B1%85%E9%85%92%E5%B1%8B).

- Kushikatsu-tengachaya Kamechan Kyobashi

For this one, it's the branch located in the Kyobashi neighborhood.

So it's clearly a chain.  The full name of the chain, cleaned up a bit from Google's simple rendering and minus branch / location, would be **Kushikatsu Tengachaya Kame-chan**.  Breaking this down into its parts:

- *Kushi* = skewers, *katsu* = deep-fried meat cutlets, so *kushikatsu* = fried meat on sticks.  ([English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kushikatsu))
- *Tengachaya* is an area in Osaka, probably where the chain first started.  ([Japanese Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kushikatsu); there isn't an English article about the area, but [there is one about the train station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tengachaya_Station))
- *Kame-chan* is a name or nickname, where *kame* = "turtle" (apparently a feminine given name, [if this ENAMDICT entry is correct](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?2MUJ%E4%BA%80)), and *-chan* is a a suffix put on names to show endearment ([WWWJDICT entry](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1MUJ%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93))

The long name can probably be shortened to just *Kame-chan*, so long as you make it clear that you're talking about the restaurant and not a person named *Kame*.

Comment: "... and not a person named Kame." Or a cute turtle